# Copying from "ThisWorkbook" problems

Tags: excel, vba

On the line "x.worksheets..." It keeps throwing back the "Subscript out of range error." The error may have something to do with the way I'm using "ThisWorkbook" but I'm not sure.  I'm still very new at this.  My objective is to copy from "ThisWorkbook" and paste values into a separate workbook.

```
Dim x As Workbook
Set x = ThisWorkbook

fmPath = "G:\Finance Department\Banking Dashboard\"
FmFile = "Testing_Testing.xlsm"
FmSheet = "Closings Template"
FmRng = "02"
fmRef = fmPath & FmFile
ToPath = "G:\Budgets and Financial\CLT Budget Templates\"
ToFile = "Belle Grove Manor.xlsx"
ToSheet = "Sheet 2"
ToRng = "E2"
ToRef = ToPath & ToFile
x.Worksheets(FmSheet).Range(FmRng).Copy
Workbooks.Open(ToRef).Worksheets(ToSheet).Activate
ActiveSheet.Range(ToRng).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't always need to declare a variable - sometimes it is easier to just refer directly to your object. The below seems like a much simpler approach than you are currently taking.

Just declare a worksheet variable `FM` for your sheet `Closings Template` instead of dimming your variables `x`, `FmSheet`, and `FmRng`

Other variables that I would get rid of are `ToSheet` and `ToRng`. Just substitute the actual value back in where these goes. Your code will be easier to follow and will require less indexing back to your variable block to know what a value is

---

The error is due to a invalid range. There is no range '02'. Typing your code out like this may help to spot those issues since you will be typing the range directly in the code like `FM.Range("O2")`

```
Sub Test1()

Dim FM As Worksheet: Set FM = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Closings Template")

FM.Range("O2").Copy

End Sub
```